# What would happen if I reversed the gravity of various manmade structures?

Tags: science-based, gravity, infrastructure

Skyscrapers appear to be pretty securely attached to the ground. So do bridges, houses, and more. But are they *really* attached to the ground?

What would happen to the structure if I was to reverse the gravity of:

1. A skyscraper
2. A modern bridge
3. A medieval bridge
4. A modern house
5. A medieval house
6. A medieval stone tower
7. Just for fun, a nuclear power plant

and are there any more manmade structures that would have interesting effects by flipping their gravity?

(Note when I say "flipping gravity", I do not mean that gravity flipped in a cuboid area, but rather only the materials that were part of the building started suddenly experiencing reverse gravity.)

Comment: "what if .... happened?" questions are clearly listed in our [help] as the sort of questions one should avoid asking here.

Comment: Agree with L.Dutch, but the short answer is they would all disintergrate as they flew up into the air.

Comment: Buildings are not designed to avoid being lifted. In particular, to take the example of the stone tower, the mortar binding together the lowermost ranks of stones has negligible strength in tension: the tower would start lifting up because there is just about nothing trying to stop it. As it lifts up, the various ranks of stones will separate, and you will soon have a swarm of independent stones. And the question as it stands now is manifestly off topic.

Comment: Isn't it obvious? Care to take a guess? I think anybody on earth can at least get very close to the answer without any research. One we know where you want to go with this, maybe one can call out smaller errors in your idea to give you a more complete picture.

Comment: How far down are you reversing the gravity? Are you including the foundation, and what about all the Earth beneath it? If you say the column extends all the way to the center of the Earth, the "reverse" weight of this would essentially turn it into a volcano with magma spewing out into space, eventually draining the entire mantle.

Comment: Also, I'd think that any untethered objects, like desks and computers in a skyscraper, would cause enough structural damage to dislodge most of the building if it didn't immediately float straight up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**All buildings, even the large ones, rely on gravity to rest them on the ground. Those that don't usually don't last long at all.**

You would be surprised that all buildings simply 'sit' on a foundation. By foundation, I mean a pile of concrete sitting on earth.

The only elements that possibly you could refer to is anti-cyclone 'tie down' rods or straps. These are designed to prevent roofs from 'lifting off' due to positive air pressure inside a building created by strong winds, or uplifting from wind caught under building eaves. However, these 'tie down' rods or straps are usually either fixed into a wall or floor slab, which is then 'resting' on the foundations.

As recently demonstrated in Cyclonic weather in the Australian northern climate regions, where there are a lot of mining towns, there were instances where mining accommodation (very similar to shipping containers) were 'lifted' and pushed over due to strong updraft winds. The resultant change to the building code meant even these temporary structures required 'tie downs'.

However this would be nothing compared to the actual weight of the building - even temporary accommodation. Most building elements are simply 'resting' on top of another - mortar in bricks is very weak bond and is easily broken.

The only exception is steel elements - these do hold together in both tension and compression. So steel structures would fair better in your 'gravity reversals' - however they would still 'fall' out of the ground, they may be intact.

So to answer:

- A skyscraper: Skyscrapers are made of steel and concrete, tied to foundations which rest on the ground. The building would lift out of the ground. Depending on the structure, the steel may hold the structure together - however the internal ceiling structures, services and cladding would 'fall' off as most connections rely on lapping joints or gravity tiling. Glass would shatter, ceilings would lift and all services within would disassemble.
- A modern bridge: If concrete, it would probably not be able to withstand the stresses of force as a lot of modern bridges are 'prestressed' - ie. they are formed with tensioned still intending for gravity to push them down to be in shape making a stronger bridge. A gravity reversal will stress this the wrong way, and would likely snap. If steel, it may be possible for it to hold together while it lifts from the ground.
- A medieval bridge: Rocks one on top of the other, usually in an arch. It would fly apart, as arches distribute force in a parabola downwards. Reversing force would render the arch redundant and break it apart.
- A modern house: Bricks are like rocks, so they would simply fly apart. The roof is steel may hold together depending on fixing details for a moment.
- A medieval house: No different to a modern house.
- A medieval stone tower: Fly apart.
- Just for fun, a nuclear power plant: The building would simply come out of the ground, however the actual reactor core would normally be reinforced concrete with re-bar inserts or grouted, in other words it would likely hold together. Everything around the core is likely going to fly apart though.

Comment: Actually for a suspension bridge, it may be indeed possible for the structure to remain connected to the ground as the cables are designed usually with screw piles to withstand pulling forces. The road may lift off the structure though.

Comment: brickwork can be pretty strong, especially in older buildings. During demolition, they sometime break like solid rock, rather than falling apart into bricks.

Answer (score -1):

As others have stated:

## The buildings would float away.

Whether you're only referring to the frame of the building, whether you're referring to the entire building and everything in it, or whether you're referring to only the furniture, the effect is the same: The building would be destroyed, and objects would fly into space away from the center of the planet.

Beds, desks, televisions, chairs, tables, refrigerators, etc: even if ONLY the furniture were to reverse gravity, that would still be hundreds to thousands of pounds of force pushing upwards on the ceilings and roof of the building, which simply aren't designed for such a thing. And I know that's not what you meant; I'm simply illustrating just how unlikely it is for a building to stay standing.

Even if only the *air* inside the building reversed gravity, you'd be in trouble; **The total weight of the atmosphere exerts a pressure of about 14.7 pounds per square inch at sea level.**

Comment: Why is there a downvote?